# Can't get large pictures on news feed when posting a link via Facebook graph api

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

When we try to post a link on our Facebook page with Facebook graph api, our pictures appears with a large size on our page wall but do not appear with a large size on 
our fans news feed.

Our links have the following OG tags :

- og:site_name

  `<meta content="Ohmymag" property="og:site_name"/>`
- og:url

  `<meta content="http://www.ohmymag.com/animaux/un-chat-joue-au-ping-pong_art77872.html" property="og:url"/>`
- og:locale

  `<meta content="fr_FR" property="og:locale" />`
- og:title

  `<meta content="Un chat joue au ping-pong" property="og:title"/>`
- og:description

  `<meta content="Les amateurs de ping-pong n'ont qu'a bien se tenir, ce chat a tout d'un futur champion de tennis de table" property="og:description"/>`
- og:type

  `<meta content="article" property="og:type">`
- og:image

  `<meta content="http://img1.ndsstatic.com/animaux/un-chat-qui-fait-du-ping-pong_148897_w620-p.jpg" property="og:image"/>` with a 620px large, 349px height and a 0.56 ratio linked picture.

We have tested different ways of posting links :

- When we publish manually, our links appear with the large size picture on both our page wall and our fans news feed.
- When we publish with Hootsuite (api), our links also appears with the large size picture on both our page wall and our fans news feed.
- When we publish by ourselves with the api, our links appears with the large size picture on our page wall but with the small size picture on our fans news feed.

To publish by ourselves, we are using Facebook graph api with PHP and Curl.

We generate our PAGE ACCESS TOKEN with the following steps :

1. We get a SHORT-LIVED USER ACCESS TOKEN, with the manages_pages and publish_stream permissions, when our page administrator log in our app.
2. We exchange the SHORT-LIVED USER ACCESS TOKEN for a LONG-LIVED USER ACCESS TOKEN with this request : `https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=xxx&client_secret=yyy&grant_type=fb_exchange_token&fb_exchange_token=zzz`
3. Finally, we get a non expirable PAGE ACCESS TOKEN with the following request : `https://graph.facebook.com/USERID/accounts?access_token=zzz`

We tried several ways of doing requests with no results :

- On "FACEBOOK_PAGE_ID/feed" (with or without the optional parameters availables : picture, name, caption, description).
- On "FACEBOOK_PAGE_ID/links" (with or without the optional parameters availables : picture, name, caption, description).

Request exemple :

```
$data['link'] = "http://www.ohmymag.com/animaux/un-chat-joue-au-ping-pong_art77872.html";
$data['access_token'] = PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN;

$post_url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/'.FACEBOOK_PAGE_ID.'/feed';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $post_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$return = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Do you think Hootsuite is white-listed or do we need to do something differently ?

Thanks.

Gaëlle.

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue and is how I found your discussion. From the details you posted I can tell you've carefully read their OG:Image specs, I don't believe it's anything you're doing wrong. I am starting to believe that this functionality is only available when posting natively OR through a "white-listed" app (as you suspect).

Answer (score 0):

Facebook don't accept og:languange , you can verify here : https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/ were you put you url. Correct is

```
<meta property="og:locale" content="fr_FR" />
```

When you verify on debuger your url and you link is whitout any error facebook fans see pictures appears with a large size.

Comment: Hi Buturca, Thank you for your answer. We changed the meta tag "og:language" to `<meta property="og:locale" content="fr_FR" />` : it still does not work. As Hootsuite was able to publish the post with a large image on the news feed, I don't think the problem come from our meta tags. Any idea ? Thanks.

Comment: On facebook only share are publish with large image, what are you doing with curl just add in feed post, not share.

Comment: Then how to "share" via API ? Hootsuite publishes on our pages via API our fans get large pictures. When we try to do the exact same thing pictures are small.